# Windows Workflow Service: how to report current state

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4

Alright, I have a bit of a dilemma. Keep in mind that I and the team I've been working with are newbs when it comes to Windows Workflow Service. We've been working on a persisted workflow that:

1. Accepts a Document, List of Approvers, List of Notifyees.
2. Emails that document to the Approvers with a Accept/Reject links.
3. Receives the response from the Accept/Reject and tallies the score.
4. Completes the the process by sending am email to all Notifyees with that tally of who accepted/rejected.

Now we are being asked to be able to return a status of who has accepted/rejected/not completed the persisted workflow process. Not sure how to accomplish this. I'm assuming we either need to build another workflow that queries the persistance DB to obtain this information or create a WCF service that does similar.

So far, most of what I've found on the Web has been pretty confusing, so... does anyone have any advice that will give me a solid direction on how to approach this particular task? It would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about querying the persistence db.

One option could be to use WF Tracking features:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513992(v=vs.110).aspx

This provides visibility into workflow execution which is close to what you need.

Another option could be that you create custom activities that save the required information to a standard database. Then you just query this information for reporting.

Comment: Yea, that's more or less the direction I was leaning: tracking or custom db. Thanks for the feedback. It helps. :)